# Keeping your statement balance below ~30% of your credit limit

Tags: credit-score, secured-credit-card

I read Little Advisor's article [How does that thing with the credit cards work, again?](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/how-does-that-thing-with-the-credit-cards-work-again/)

According to the article, you should always keep your balance below 30% of your credit limit.  However, I just recently got a secured credit card from Capital One, with a "credit" limit of $200.

Does the 30% guideline apply to secured cards as well?

Comment: Yes!  Keep it at zero.  Best way to do this is cut it up.

Comment: @PeteBelford - sorry I can't DV a comment. Cut it up? Really? You one of those 'credit use is evil' people?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer:  Yes if it robs one of wealth.  This seems like a case of just that.  Many people see credit as inevitable.  I see it as a last resort with only a strong business case.  Do I use a CC to travel and for reoccurring payments?  Yes, paid in full each month.  Do I use a CC at a restaurant or for shopping?  Never.  Research, and my experience, has shown that people spend more when doing so.  In other words that is a negative business case.

Comment: Ok, not sure what happened to that answer, but it's gone now...  ???

Comment: @quantycuenta Sorry, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This thinking has shifted and shifted again over the years.  It used to be recommended that one should maintain an approximate 30% balance to achieve the highest score.

Credit Karma has an [excellent random sample of 70,000 credit scores](https://www.creditkarma.com/article/CreditCardUtilizationAndScore):

[image]

To achieve the highest score by this reliable sample, one should maintain a 1-10% balance.

Why the large drop at 0%?  Creditors must be assured that a borrower can manage credit, namely regular interest payments.

Credit scoring is fairly accurate at determining default risk as shown by [VantageScore's calculation based upon TransUnion data](http://www.money-zine.com/financial-planning/debt-consolidation/about-credit-scores/):

[image]

For creditors to be able to produce credit, the cost of default risk must be compensated, and [this is done via the price of credit, the interest rate](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/business/2013/09/how-much-does-your-credit-score-cost-you/):

**Auto loans**

[image]

**Credit cards**

[image]

**Mortgages**

[image]

In short, one should keep a 1-10% balance of all available credit card credit, including secured credit cards.

Comment: So, I should only spend $2 - $20?  I was planning to use this card to pay my $80/month phone bill.

Comment: @Soviero I would go ahead and use it on the phone bill.  You take a credit hit for high utilization but it's temporary, it goes away as soon as you get the utilization back down.

Comment: @LorenPechtel How temporary?  How long does it take for  my score to recover once I get my utilization down (or my credit limit up)?